# Force scipy.stats.cauchy between an interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I would like to `force scipy.stats.cauchy` probability density function to only generate values between -1 and 1.

Currently I am doing the hacky way by running `y=cauchy.rvs(center,sigma)` inside a while loop and while its lower than -1 or higher than 1 it recomputes it and after it enters the desired interval it returns y. So essentially I am drawing a new random variable until the conditions are not met.

I am wondering whether it's possible to do this in a simpler way, the scipy documentation is not very helpful and it's very ambiguous. Is there any way to specify the min/max range of the random variables inside the function arguments, like via **kwargs or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Not directly, no.

The issue is that a distribution is normalized, the integral of the pdf over the support is unity. When you change the support, you are effectively changing the distribution.

For the truncated Cauchy distribution, you can easily roll your own little generator, using the inverse function transform of a uniform random variate.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately there is no inverse function in the scipy package, and instead of manually inputting it, which would be long, I think I'll keep my while loop, it's more efficient this way, at least for small deviations that I would use, where it rarely goes outside of the boundary, otherwise it would indeed be burdensome and the loop would be very slow, but in this case ,I think I will stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

@ev-br is correct, there is not a built-in way to do this with SciPy or NumPy. @ev-br is also correct that "you can easily roll your own little generator, using the inverse function transform of a uniform random variate".  You say in a comment "unfortunately there is no inverse function in the scipy package, and instead of manually inputting it, which would be long, I think I'll keep my while loop...", but actually the formulas are pretty simple.  (And actually, there is an inverse of the CDF of the Cauchy distribution, `scipy.stats.cauchy.ppf`,  but here I'll implement the formula directly.)

Here's a truncated Cauchy sampler that uses the inverse transform:

```
import numpy as np


def truncated_cauchy_rvs(loc=0, scale=1, a=-1, b=1, size=None):
    """
    Generate random samples from a truncated Cauchy distribution.

    `loc` and `scale` are the location and scale parameters of the distribution.
    `a` and `b` define the interval [a, b] to which the distribution is to be
    limited.

    With the default values of the parameters, the samples are generated
    from the standard Cauchy distribution limited to the interval [-1, 1].
    """
    ua = np.arctan((a - loc)/scale)/np.pi + 0.5
    ub = np.arctan((b - loc)/scale)/np.pi + 0.5
    U = np.random.uniform(ua, ub, size=size)
    rvs =  loc + scale * np.tan(np.pi*(U - 0.5))
    return rvs
```

For example,

```
In [57]: x = truncated_cauchy_rvs(loc=0.25, scale=1/3, size=200000)                                

In [58]: ignore = plt.hist(x, bins=100, density=True, color='green', alpha=0.25)                   

In [59]: plt.grid(alpha=0.5)
```

[image: histogram]